# Prove that a Lipschitz function is continuous. Must a Lipschitz function necessarily be differentiable?

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions

I have:

Pf. Let epsilon>0 be given. Select a delta such that delta is less than epsilon/M so that |x-y| is less than delta. Then|(f(x)-f(y)| is less than M|x-y| is less than M(delta) is less than epsilon. So |f(x)-f(y)| is less than epsilon
So f is continuous.

Now I do not know how to show that Lipschitz does not imply differentiability unless i use counterexample f(x)=|x|.

Then, there is also a T/F statement: If f is Lipschitz on R, then f attains its max and min values.

Answer (score 1):

Try the T/F statement (about attaining the max) on the example you gave: $f(x) = |x|$.

And if you want other examples of a function that is Lipschitz but fails to be differentiable at multiple points, consider the [Triangle wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_wave).  Now, this one does attain its mins and maxes.  However, if we add to the Triangle wave (denote it $w(x)$) the function $x$, then the resulting function,
$$
w(x) + x,
$$
is Lipschitz, still fails to be differentiable at multiple points, and does not attain its min or max.

Comment: f(x)=|x| would not attain the max and min values, correct? @avs

Comment: Would attain the min, but has no max.